# SQL Server - Create user that can only read and write data from and to database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, security, authentication

I need to share my project with some colleagues, and I want to create a SQL Server user for them, so that user should not be able to drop database, I need him only to read and write to SQL Server tables, so I'm wondering are these settings ok:

[image]

And here is another settings:

[image]

Is this enough to prevent them from dropping database? But also enough to give them access to read and write the database? Maybe I checked something that I shouldn't?

Comment: Dropping tables or dropping an entire database?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1ffed52e-d9df-41f6-9fa8-575a3026730f/how-to-prevent-users-from-dropping-databases?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: And https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/getting-started-with-database-engine-permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't give both `db_datareader` (allow to read all tables and view) and `db_denydatareader` (because this **prevents** a user from reading any table or view) at the same time.

The `deny` is stronger than the positive permission, so if you use both at the same time, the user **won't be able** to read from any table or view.

**Just** the `db_datareader` will be fine (and `db_datawriter`, if the users should be able to insert and update data, too)

Answer (score 0):

disable the writter options from user mapping